# How can I make this DECLARE PROCEDURE working?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-18c

I'm new to Oracle DB, coming from MS SQL Server.

I created this script:

```
DEFINE USER_NAME = &1
DEFINE PASSWORD = &2
DEFINE TABLESPACE = &3

CONNECT &DB_ADMIN/&DB_PWD@//localhost:1521/&DB_NAME

SET VERIFY OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF

DECLARE PROCEDURE Create_User
  ( userName IN VARCHAR2
  , password IN VARCHAR2
  , tSpace IN VARCHAR2
  ) AS
  dbCount INTEGER := -1;
  createStmt VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO dbCount
    FROM CDB_USERS u
      INNER JOIN v$pdbs d ON u.CON_ID = d.CON_ID
    WHERE d.NAME = '&DB_NAME'
      AND u.USERNAME = userName;

  IF dbCount > 0
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' || userName || ' CASCADE';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User ' || userName || ' dropped.');
    END IF;

  createStmt := 'CREATE USER ' || userName || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || password || ' DEFAULT TABLESPACE ' || tSpace || ' QUOTA UNLIMITED ON ' || tSpace;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User about to be created:');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(createStmt);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating user ' || userName || ' ...');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE createStmt;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Database ' || userName || ' successfully created.');

  END Create_User;

BEGIN
  Create_User('&USER_NAME', '&PASSWORD', '&TABLESPACE');
  END;
  /
```

When I run it in SqlPlus, like this:

```
SQL> DEFINE DB_NAME = 'MYDB'
SQL> DEFINE DB_ADMIN = 'SA'
SQL> DEFINE DB_PWD = 'pwd'
SQL> @/db-install/sql/add-user.sql 'USERNAME' 'pwd' 'TSPACE'
```

I get this error message:

```
Connected.
DECLARE PROCEDURE Create_User
*
ERROR at line 1:
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'USERNAME' does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 19
ORA-06512: at line 36
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Your answer is appreciated.

---

### EDIT

I have this exact same code in another script, and it's working fine there:

```
DEFINE DB_NAME = &1
DEFINE DB_ADMIN = &2
DEFINE DB_PWD = &3

CONNECT &DB_ADMIN/&DB_PWD@//localhost:1521/&DB_NAME

SET VERIFY OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Adding tablespaces to database ...');
  END;
  /


--- Procedure: dropping and creating a given tablespace ---
DECLARE
  dbCount INTEGER;
  createStmt VARCHAR2(500);
  filePath dba_data_files.FILE_NAME%TYPE;
PROCEDURE Create_TS
...
```

### EDIT 2

It doesn't make a difference if I put the variables between `DECLARE` and `PROCEDURE`:

```
DECLARE
  dbCount INTEGER := -1;
  createStmt VARCHAR2(500);
PROCEDURE Create_User
  ( userName IN VARCHAR2
  , password IN VARCHAR2
  , tSpace IN VARCHAR2
  ) AS
BEGIN
```

```
Connected.
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'USERNAME' does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 19
ORA-06512: at line 36
```

Comment: What is the full error message? For example I get this: `DECLARE PROCEDURE Create_User
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'TSPACE' does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 29
ORA-06512: at line 35`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, @Balasz. I amended my report with additional error message details now. It's weird: I'm trying to create a user with this procedure, but the error message is claiming that the user doesn't exist. In the code I'm never referring to an existing user.

Comment: @Balasz, your clever comment brought me to the solution to my problem: The `PROCEDURE` parameter `userName` conflicted with the column `CDB_USERS.USERNAME`, which resulted in a stack overflow.

After renaming the `PROCEDURE` parameter from `userName` to `usrName`, everything works fine.

See https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06512.php

Would you want to provide this as an answer? I'd be happy to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that is a great example why you should never name your PL/SQL variables the same as column names.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE Create_User
  ( userName IN VARCHAR2
  , password IN VARCHAR2
  , tSpace IN VARCHAR2
  ) AS
  dbCount INTEGER := -1;
  createStmt VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO dbCount
    FROM DBA_USERS u
    WHERE u.USERNAME = userName;
  dbms_output.put_line('User count: ' || dbcount);
end;
begin
  create_user('abc', 'abc', 'abc');
end;
/

User count: 26
```

The `u.USERNAME = userName` filter is `username = username`, which returns all rows where username is not null.

Comment: Thank you, @Balazs, yet, I don't want the procedure to be stored in the database. It's supposed to be a temporary procedure in memory.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this example: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-855AA11F-32CB-4CAD-9255-BE92A6821487

Comment: _"I don't want the procedure to be stored in the database. It's supposed to be a temporary procedure in memory"_  Then why have a pl/sql procedure at all?  Creating a user is a simple one-line command.  Why not just a simple sql script, or just create them from a command line in sqlplus or SQL Dev?  Also, Id' be wary of your unconditional DROP ... CASCADE.  You could some serious damage that way.